# How to avoid inserting duplicate records from XML file

Tags: sql

I am inserting records from an XML file into a SQL table

My procedure looks like this

```
 insert into Employees(id, name, phone, ssn)

 select 
NEWID(),
Employee.value('(id/text())[1]','uniqueidentifier'),
Employee.value('(name/text())[1]','varchar(50)'),
Employee.value('(phone/text())[1]','varchar(15)'),
Employee.value('(ssn/text())[1]','varchar(15)'),

FROM
  @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfEmployee/Employee')AS TEMPTABLE(Employee)
```

I cannot make any changes to the XML file. 
How can I avoid inserting duplicate rows in the table?

Thank you

Comment: Unique constraint?

Answer (score 0):

When uniqueidentifier is unique then you could create a unique constraint for that rwo.